# C programming, meaningless figures on console

Tags: c

I wrote code to reverse a sentence that the user inputs, but when I run this code and write a sentence, this code prints meaningless figures instead of reverse version of my sentence. I need helping locating the error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverser(char*);
int readmassage(char[], int);

int main()
{
    char mysentence[30];

    readmassage(mysentence, 30);
    reverser(mysentence);
    printf("%s", mysentence);
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void reverser(char *massage)
{
    char temp,*p;
    p = massage + strlen(massage)-1;
    while (p > massage) {
        temp = *massage;
        *massage = *p;
        *p-- = temp;
    }
}

int readmassage(char massage[], int lenght)
{
    int ch, i = 0;
    while (ch = getchar() != '\n') {
        if (lenght > i)
            massage[i++] = ch;
    }
    massage[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: And the message that gets logged to the console is...?

Comment: Your code has a bunch of warnings. A lot of mistakes can be understood from compiler warnings. Unfortunately many compilers have warnings off by default. Turn them on, and see if fixing them helps. For most command line compilers `-fsanitize=address -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic` is a good set of warnings to start with.

Comment: You should decide whether `main` is a void function or not. You claim it is void and then you return 0.

Comment: Was the assignment to reverse the sentence word for word or to reverse the string character by character?

Comment: @jwdonahue I want to reverse word by word for example when i write "example" it should be "elpmaxe"

Comment: See the [mcve] definition -- questions should include a *specific problem or error* in the question itself, alongside the shortest code needed to produce it. "Meaningless figures" as a description is much less helpful than providing a specific example of that undesired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
temp = *massage;
*massage = *p;
*p-- = temp;
```

`massage` always points to the first character in your string here. So you keep overwriting the first character, and then writing the new first character to the last character on the next go round. The effect is that you essentially rotate the string by one character instead of reversing it. If you change `*massage = *p;` to `*massage++ = *p;` (or create a new incrementing pointer variable to correspond to `p` which you initialize to `massage`), it'll probably work.

What I'm saying is that your "start of the string" pointer needs to be... massaged. *ba dum chshhhh*

**EDIT:** And you also need to change this, in `readmessage`:

```
while (ch = getchar() != '\n')
```

to:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
```

Otherwise, rather than the input character, you're actually setting `ch` to `0` or `1`, depending on whether `getchar()` is returning `'\n'` or not. This is because due to the order of operations, `!=` actually gets executed before `=`, and `!=` gives you `1` if the expression is true and `0` if it is false. This `0` or `1` then gets stored in `ch` by the `=` operator.

You could also just replace all of `readmessage` with `fgets`, as it's included in the standard library and meant for exactly this sort of thing (unless reimplementing it was part of your assignment, of course).

Comment: Thank you, i changed that line, but it is still printing same figures.

Comment: @OlcayA. What "figures"? Are you talking about the compiler warnings? If so, follow the suggestions in the warnings.

Comment: I think you need parentheses around the `getchar()` assignment, i.e. `while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')`. In C, `!=` [has higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=` and so the value stored in `ch` is the result of the logical comparison, not the character itself. `gcc -Wall` warns about this: `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]`

Comment: @TypeIA You're absolutely correct. I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Not compiler warning, just meaningless figures is printed on console

Comment: @OlcayA. I've edited TypeIA's correction into the answer; if your code still does not behave, please post the "figures" you're talking about.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Thank you, meaningles figures problem is solved but now ı have another problems with code I will try to fix them :).

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Okey i fixed them too, thank you for all , i am grateful for your helps.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**
Adding explanation. There are some issues with your code, few major, few not that serious

1. Don't use `void main()`. It's not the best thing to use.
2. Indenting your code will make it easier to read
3. Let's look at the `readmassage` function.
4. You are assigning the result of `getchar()` to an `int`. That's not right. it should be a `char`

here's a version of your code with minor fixes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void reverser(char*);
int readmassage(char[], int);
void main()
{
    char mysentence[30];
    readmassage(mysentence, 30);
    printf("Input: %s", mysentence);
    reverser(mysentence);
    printf("Output: %s", mysentence);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void reverser(char*massage)
{
    char temp,*p;
    p = massage + strlen(massage)-1;
    while (p > massage) {
    temp = *massage;
    *massage = *p;
    *p-- = temp;
}}
int readmassage(char massage[], int lenght)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
      ch = getchar();
      printf("Here\n");
      if (lenght > i)
      {
        massage[i++] = ch;
        printf("%c\n", massage[i]);
      }
    }
    massage[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

When you try this you will find that the input string gets read fine, just be sure to not to hi `Enter` after every character and instead type the full string out as `\n` is a valid character that can be in the stream and will terminate the loop the next iteration.

This is why you should use a char array reading function like `fgets`.

Once you get here you can see that the `reverser` is just following a slightly flawed reversing logic.

grammatical errors aside, fixing this you can get

here you go

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverser(char* message)
{
    int start, end;
    start = 0;
    end = strlen(message) - 1;
    char temp;
    while (start < end) {
      temp = message[start];
      message[start] = message[end];
      message[end] = temp;
      start++;
      end--;
    }
}
void readmessage(char message[], int length)
{
    fgets(message, length , stdin);
} 

int main()
{
    char mysentence[30];
    readmessage(mysentence, 30);
    printf("Read the string\n");
    reverser(mysentence);
    printf("%s\n", mysentence);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a "plz send teh codez" answer with no explanation, -1.

Comment: -1. This is an obvious homework assignment. Rewriting the OP's code with zero explanation why it is better than the original is not really very helpful.

Comment: agreed on both counts, I'll edit it to add more details

Comment: Thank you, your code is working well but i want to see where is my mistake on my code

Answer (score -2):

please debugg to find out the reason sometimes.. It will help you..
The problem is when you call readmassage(mysentence, 30) inside the function you have the string input.
When the flow comes back to the method the value is no more there as you had passed mysentence by value..
And you send null to reverse()..
Pass by reference will work..

Comment: -1, there are several problems with the posted code but this is not one of them. The "string" is not "passed by value", it is stored in an array whose address is passed.

Comment: Thanks by sentence was wrong. No problem with -1.. I still think it wont work with local variable..

Comment: Incorrect: it will and you can prove it to yourself with simple experimentation (or basic knowledge of C).